# Wordpress batch for move posts status for custom type

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

Is there any way for change all custom posts type status change from "publish" to Draft ?

Scenario:
 Here I need to run a script.
 my post type is: property_listing
 Now I need to make all post draft then perform my custom operation.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Cpanel or database access you can run this query in DB panel.

```
update table wp_posts set status='draft' where post_type='property_listing'
```

otherwise, use this code.( paste it in your theme function.php)

```
add_action('init','change_mypost_status');
function change_mypost_status(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' =>  'property_listing',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            $current_post = array(
                  'ID'           => get_the_ID(),
                  'post_status' => 'draft'
              );
            // Update the post into the database
              wp_update_post( $current_post );
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```